# When does a rowupdate, rowupdating, rowdeleted, rowdeleting events get fired

Tags: asp.net

When do these events actually fire. Msdn speaks about the update button. I dont have any update button in my gridview so which update button does the site talk about?

Comment: Have you enabled updating in the gridview?

Answer (score 1):

Well, when you enable editing on your gridview, it would put the Edit button on your gridview. After that, when a user clicks on Edit, the gridview generates an Update button. Same for the Delete button, it comes when you enable delete on the gridview.

Comment: not satisfactory enough. I found the answer. When we use edit,update or delete for commandname attribute the corresponding events are fired.